# How do databases "update" records?

Tags: database, database-design

As far as I can tell, it is not really possible to "update" a single portion of a file. One must overwrite the entire thing or simply append. A database, however, usually has update functionality. How would one design a database to not append - because that causes tombstones - but rather update?

Comment: It is certainly possible to overwrite a portion of a file.

Comment: Databases do tend to create toombstones as you say, but they also incorporate all sorts of code to either re-use space if it can, or collect empty space and reorganise pages, etc etc. All part of the day to day operations of a database. Remember its not one big file, it will be collections of buckets that can be reorganised as required. And yes, empty space is often allocated. All part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Files can be overwritten it just can be a bit of a tedious process. You will have to know the beginning index of whatever you want to update and set the file pointer to that index in the file before starting to write to that file.

Databases are easier to update because they are a combination of many data structures (Linked lists, Trees, Heaps, etc.) that all contain specific data and can be iterated through. For these data structures you just need to know which node in the structure you need to update and navigate to it and overwrite the data.